# How get only the name of an object and transform it to string dynamically?

Tags: javascript, object, stringify

I would transform the name of an object dynamically in string.

I would transform the name of the object in string to retrieve it dynamically. 
output desired:

> "CartModel"

Currently it returns me

> "[object Object]"

Here my object:

```js
var CartModel= {
  userID:{ 
   beverage:{ 
    // value
   },
   sandwich:{ 

   },
   treat:{

   },
   dessert:{

   }
  }
  
   }
   
console.log('"' + CartModel + '"');
```

any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: the object does not know its name ...

Comment: You could use ES6 shorthand property syntax to create an object and get the name: `console.log(Object.keys({CartModel})[0])` but you already know that since it's your code. Why do you need this?

Comment: That name "variable' is hard-code. It won't change. If I get it correctly you want to figure out the name of something hard-coded. Just use the name you typed.

Comment: there is necessary a mean to retrieve the name of the object in a string way

Comment: your use case is unclear. WHY do you want to do this? For what purpose. Perhaps there is a way to solve your problem if you tell us what the problem is rather than what you want your solution to be.

Comment: Okay I want to verify in my database if there is a specific object, so using Redis currently, Redis needs the object's name, hence I need to stringify the object's name, that's my WHY

Comment: The name of the variable that refers to the object is not the object's name.

Comment: I want the name of the variable that refers to the object.

Comment: @Pointy can you elaborate please?

Comment: Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Identifier. 2nd paragraph, third sentence.

Comment: @RandyCasburn  hmmm. thanks for this document

Comment: besides, you access redis data structures with redis keys. The key is unlikley to be the javascript identifier.

Comment: @RandyCasburn why it couldn't be? a key is just an identifier in some way

Comment: sure, but look at the code that stores your Object structure into redis. A Redis key was either provided by code or auto-generated and returned. THAT key is what you need to perform a look up in redis.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for an object to return the name of the *variable* it's assigned to. This is impossible. An object doesn't know the name of the variable it's assigned to. Some objects can be assigned to multiple variables, and it's also possible that an object isn't assigned to any variable.

You can customise the value an object displays when it is converted to a String by overriding `toString()`. For example

```
CartModel.toString = function () {
  return 'CartModel';
}
```

Now if you call

```
console.log('"' + CartModel + '"');
```

`"CartModel"` will be shown in the console:

Comment: I don't know I think your solution is interesting

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print whole object in string then you can use JSON.stringify(obj) method

```js
var obj = {
  name:"abc",
  value:{
    a:1,
    b:2
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

EDIT:
In case of printing name of the object you can create a class (function) of the object using new keyword and print the name using constructor

```js
function test(x, y){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

var abc = new test(1,2);
console.log(abc.constructor.name);
```

Comment: I want just to stringify the object variable name

Answer (score 0):

If it were a function instead of an object you could retrieve it's name.

Or you could provide a `toString` method ie. `var User = { toString: () => 'some name' };`

Then if you perform an action that calls the objects toString method it would work.

Comment: I want just to stringify the object variable name